# Where are all the XMPP user name and password saved

Tags: xmpp

When there is a domain created and username and password for the domain is registered to chat on the XMPP. Where does these username and password be saved.

Are these stored on Jabber server's database, or we create a database on our server and store them.

Like sunil@sunil.com is stored in jabber server database or on sunil.com database.

Any link to through more light on this will also be help full

Cheers
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the Jabber server used. Some Jabber servers are able to store the usernames and passwords in an internal database, but most server implementations also let you configure an external database, such as MySQL or Postgres, or let you use LDAP for the user database.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I am implementing a node.js xmpp server, how do I store the users, and also using it on centos OS